# SQLite query: get index of row after sort where

Tags: sqlite, syntax

I need to find the index in a table of a specific row and also select it.
I need both, the index and the row.
Any ideas?

**EDIT**: by 'index' I refer to position in the table after being ordered.

This question could be a duplicate, but I don't know what to look for.

Comment: Define "index" in this context.

Comment: I'm trying to find the position of the row in the table.

Answer (score -1):

SQL database are fundamentally unordered.  There is no index or row number in a table.  Unless you explicitly order the results with ORDER BY in a SELECT clause there is no guarantee that the rows will be returned to you in the same order in two successive queries.

To uniquely identify a row, you must ensure that you know which column (or combination of column values) are uniquely identify a row and include these terms in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Let's say that I have a table with two columns: "Name" and "Age".
I will order the table by "Age" column and I want to find out at which position in this ordered list I will find a specific name.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?  In your example if there are multiple people with the same age, the apparent order in the result set might change between queries.

Comment: I don't mind if the order changes between queries. I need to display a text which says something like that: "You're 18th oldest person".